# Extract the type of a callable in mypy

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Say I have these functions:

```
def mogrify(a: int) -> bool:
    return bool(a)

def stream(b: int, f: Callable[[int], bool]) -> bool:
    return f(b)
```

I have one canonical callback, so I would like to, instead, be able to do
something like:

```
MyCallback = reveal_type(mogrify)

def stream(b: int, f: MyCallback) -> bool:
    return f(b)
```

In addition to not actually doing what I want, `reveal_type` itself isn't part
of PEP 484 so I can't use that.

Comment: There's currently no way to extract the type of a function AFAIK, though it may be worth asking on the issue tracker just in case it happens to be in the works (there's currently some ongoing work on making callable signatures more precise). In the meantime, type aliases are probably your next best bet -- do `MyCallback = Callable[[int], bool]` somewhere, then do `def stream(b: int, f: MyCallback) -> bool:`.

Comment: There's no way to do that. But if you follow @Michael0x2a suggestion to use a type alias, and annotate everything with it (including the canonical function), you won't type any extra type hints. The only disadvantage is that a type alias is separated from argument names, so it's slightly harder to read/write it. Feel free to submit a feature request on the issue tracker if you like.

Comment: Thanks, I am currently using the type alias, and it's fine. I'm not sure how I'd go about annotating the canonical function with a `Callable` type?